# Isomorphism $\phi:G\to G\times G$

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, group-isomorphism

Can anyone provide me with an example of a non-trivial group $G$ which is isomorphic to $G\times G$. What is the mapping $G \to G\times G$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint : take $G=\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and find a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ onto the union of two copies of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I am not at that level I guess...could u please define it too.. Thnx in advance

Comment: I got it...thnx